# Concurrent/Continuous Testing for nodejs (ncrunch for nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, continuous-integration, ncrunch

I'm a big fan of the continuous testing setup offered by [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net) in Visual Studio, and would love to have a similar setup with nodejs.

When writing JavaScript in node I use Sublime Text 2 as my editor, with tests written using Mocha.

I wondered if there was software (or a ST2 plugin) for achieving similar concurrent testing to that offered by NCrunch when writing .NET code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing some digging around I've decided that the solution for the moment is:

**Server-side:** [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/)

```
mocha -w test
```

Using [mocha's built-in watch functionality](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/#watch-option).

**Client-side**: [Testacular](https://github.com/vojtajina/testacular#testacular--)

I'm now using [testacular](https://github.com/vojtajina/testacular#testacular--), which is truly awesome. It would be great it if had hooks for running the server-side watch progress in tandem, but not really a problem.

Comment: But could you have close to NCrunch functionality with Testacular, now Karma? I mean code analysis, code highlighting etc?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself yet but it looks promising: [wallaby.js](http://wallabyjs.com/) The description from the website has the following description

> Wallaby.js is an intelligent test runner for JavaScript that
>   continuously runs your tests. It reports code coverage and other
>   results directly to your code editor immediately as you change your
>   code. Wallaby.js uses various tricks to run your tests as fast as
>   possible, such as dependency analysis to only execute tests affected
>   by your code changes and parallel test execution.

Comment: I've now tried it. After a little fighting getting all the paths right, wallaby.js is now running smoothly in an angular/requirejs environment. ( I am currently using the visual studio plugin ). Thus, it still looks promising...